# Stacked SQL Query error and complications

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, phpmyadmin

I just learned you can stack SQL queries instead of running 4 different ones and combining the data. So I'm read tutorials and stuff but still can't figure this certain one out.

```
SELECT ID,
       (SELECT firstname
        FROM   user
        WHERE  ID = fundraiser.user_ID) AS firstname,
       (SELECT lastname
        FROM   user
        WHERE  ID = fundraiser.user_ID) AS lastname,
       (SELECT org_fund_id
        FROM   fundraiser
        WHERE  ID = fundraiser.ID)      AS org_fund_ID,
       (SELECT ref_ID
        FROM   fundraiser
        WHERE  ID = fundraiser.ID)      AS ref_ID
FROM   fundraiser
WHERE  1
ORDER  BY org_fund_ID ASC
```

Here's the basic setup for the database/tables being called:
[fundraiser] - (ID, ref_ID, user_ID, org_fund_ID) and 
[user] - (firstname, lastname)

Basically, I want to pull all of the fields from "fundraiser" from the database but get the corresponding "user.firstname" and "user.lastname" where "fundraiser.user_ID" = "user.ID".

So it would come out something like this as a row:
fundraiser.ID, fundraiser.user_ID, fundraiser.ref_ID, user.firstname, user.lastname

I've tried like 30 different ways of writing this query and all have failed. The error I get is "#1242 - Subquery returns more than 1 row".

Not sure how I can give you more information so you can visualize what I'm talking about, but I will provide whatever data I can.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

to select ALL columns:

```
SELECT *
FROM   fundraiser f
       INNER JOIN user u
               ON u.ID = f.user_ID
ORDER  BY f.ord_fund_id ASC;
```

to select **needed** columns:

```
SELECT 
    u.firstname,
    u.lastname,
    f.org_fund_id,
    f.ref_ID
FROM fundraiser f 
INNER JOIN user u ON u.ID = f.user_ID
ORDER BY f.ord_fund_id ASC;
```

this should be, what you need. See [this Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Join_%28SQL%29).

Comment: That pulls every field from the user table (there are a lot more than just firstname and lastname. I'll read up on the JOIN aspect, though. Thank you.

Comment: You, my friend, are a life saver. I've still got a lot to learn in terms of SQL. Thanks for the help and also pointing me in the right direction for learning more. Very much appreciated.